# Why one snakemake rule is always skipped or ignored

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I am trying to fix a Snakefile. There are two rules (see the code below), each one would work if it's the only one, but only the rule `prernaseqc` would work when both are kept.

It seems that `snakemake` totally ignores the other.

I tried to touch file `files_to_rnaseqc.txt` etc, and it does not help. Why?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
import os
configfile: "run.json"
workpath = config['project']['workpath']

samples=sorted(list(config['project']['units'].keys()))

from snakemake.utils import R
from os.path import join
configfile: "run.json"

from os import listdir

star_dir="STAR_files"
bams_dir="bams"
log_dir="logfiles"
rseqc_dir="RSeQC"
kraken_dir="kraken"
preseq_dir="preseq"
pfamily = 'rnaseq'


rule prernaseqc:
   input: 
    expand(join(workpath,bams_dir,"{name}.star_rg_added.sorted.dmark.bam"), name=samples)
   output:
    out1=join(workpath,bams_dir,"files_to_rnaseqc.txt")
   priority: 2
   params: 
    rname='pl:prernaseqc',batch='--mem=4g --time=04:00:00'
   run:
        with open(output.out1, "w") as out:
            out.write("Sample ID\tBam file\tNotes\n")
            for f in input:
                out.write("%s\t"  % f)
                out.write("%s\t"  % f)
                out.write("%s\n"  % f)
            out.close()

rule rnaseqc:
   input:
    join(workpath,bams_dir,"files_to_rnaseqc.txt")
   output:
    join(workpath,"STAR_QC")
   priority: 2
   params: 
    rname='pl:rnaseqc',
    batch='--mem=24g --time=48:00:00',
    bwaver=config['bin'][pfamily]['tool_versions']['BWAVER'],
    rrnalist=config['references'][pfamily]['RRNALIST'],
    rnaseqcver=config['bin'][pfamily]['RNASEQCJAR'],
    rseqcver=config['bin'][pfamily]['tool_versions']['RSEQCVER'],   
    gtffile=config['references'][pfamily]['GTFFILE'],
    genomefile=config['references'][pfamily]['GENOMEFILE']

   shell: """
module load {params.bwaver}
module load {params.rseqcver}

var="{params.rrnalist}"
if [  $var == "-" ]; then
      java -Xmx48g -jar {params.rnaseqcver} -n 1000 -s {input} -t {params.gtffile} -r {params.genomefile}  -o {output}
else
      java -Xmx48g -jar {params.rnaseqcver} -n 1000 -s {input} -t {params.gtffile} -r {params.genomefile} -rRNA {params.rrnalist}  -o {output}
fi
```

Comment: thank you for edit the question, but "until I touched the file" should be deleted from the question. Touching the file does not help.

Comment: How are you running Snakemake? Just `snakemake`? You need to edit your question to include this crucial info.

Answer (score 1):

Snakemake, by design, uses output files listed in first rule of the file as target files (i.e. files that need to be created). Hence, in your case, whichever rule happens to be the first gets executed, while the other remains unexecuted.

You need to [specify a target rule](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) that lists all output files. It is customary to name it `rule all`.

```
rule all:
    input:
        join(workpath,bams_dir,"files_to_rnaseqc.txt"),
        join(workpath,"STAR_QC")
```